# Center an image horizontally and vertically in a table with ConTeXt

Tags: tables, context

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\enableregime[utf-8]
\usemodule  [simplefonts][size=12pt]
\setmainfont[EB Garamond 12][expansion=quality,protrusion=quality]
\setuppagenumbering[location=]
\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global,default}]
\setupTABLE[r][odd][height=1.5cm,align={middle,lohi}]
\setupTABLE[r][even][height=5cm,align={middle,lohi}]
\setupTABLE[c][1][width=2cm,align={middle,lohi}]
\setupTABLE[c][2,3][width=8cm,align={middle,lohi}]
\starttext
\placetable[here,none]{}{%
\bTABLE
\bTR\bTD{}\eTD\bTH {$a>0$\\P est tournée vers le haut}\eTH\bTH{$a<0$\\P est tournée vers le bas}\eTH\eTR
\bTR\bTD{$\Delta>0$}\eTD \bTD \dontleavehmode\externalfigure[cow][width=4cm]\eTD\bTD \dontleavehmode\externalfigure[cow][width=4cm]\eTD\eTR
\bTR\bTD [nc=3]\startquotation $f(x)$ est du signe de $a$ à l'extérieur des racines et du signe de $-a$ à l'intérieur des racines \stopquotation\eTD\eTR
\bTR\bTD{$\Delta<0$}\eTD \bTD \dontleavehmode\externalfigure[cow][width=4cm]\eTD\bTD \dontleavehmode\externalfigure[cow][width=4cm]\eTD\eTR
\bTR\bTD [nc=3]\startquotation $f(x)$ est du signe de $a$ pour tout $x\neq \frac{-b}{2a}$\stopquotation\eTD\eTR
\bTR\bTD{$\Delta=0$}\eTD \bTD \dontleavehmode\externalfigure[cow][width=4cm]\eTD\bTD \dontleavehmode\externalfigure[cow][width=4cm]\eTD\eTR
\bTR\bTD [nc=3]\startquotation $f(x)$ est du signe de $a$ pour tout $x$ réel\stopquotation\eTD\eTR
\eTABLE}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Add `\dontleavehmode` before `\externalfigure`. See [ConTeXt Wiki: Images at beginning of paragraph](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Using_Graphics#Images_at_the_beginning_of_a_paragraph) for details.

Comment: @ Aditya Thank you, it works (I discovered ConteXt).
But if possible, I would like some further explanation.

Comment: @Fabrice [Another related Wiki section](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Unexpected_behavior#Unsolicited_Vertical_Mode)

Comment: @ pgh Thank you, it's more clear.
A small issue that is not directly related to this post: how to center the table in the page ?

Comment: @Fabrice: `\midaligned{\bTABLE .. \eTABLE}` or `\placetable[here,none]{}{\bTABLE .. \eTABLE}`

Comment: @Aditya It's better, but I do not understand why the right margin is not the same size as the left margin. Normally, there should be 1.5 cm (21-8-8-2).

Comment: @Fabrice. It is hard to guess without a minimal example.

Comment: @Aditya The minimal example that I gave in this post is not enough ?

Comment: @ Aditya `\setuppapersize[A4]
\setuplayout [backspace=0cm,width=middle,
topspace=1cm,height=middle,
location=middle,marking=on]`

Comment: @Aditya care to answer this one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved in the comments.